# how to apply dozer converter at global level

Tags: dozer

Is there a way to apply the custom converter at global level for all classes.

I am trying to avoid to have every class specified in the mapping.xml file.
I want some thing like this

```
<mapping map-null="false">
    <class-a>*</class-a>
    <class-b>*</class-b>  
</mapping>
```

I found the answer by myself

```
<configuration> 
 <map-null>false</map-null> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: I solved it myself. You need to add                                                     <configuration>
   <map-null>false</map-null>
  </configuration>

Comment: you should add that as an answer and then accept it when you are able to